# How to merge numpy arrays stored in a nested list in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested-lists

I have a list of numpy arrays and want to split it into chunks based on the length of array. This is my list:

```
import numpy as np
nums=[[np.array([[1.]]), np.array([[2.]])],\
      [np.array([[3.]]), np.array([[5.]])],\
      [np.array([[3.], [3.]]), np.array([[8.], [9.]])],\
      [np.array([[8.], [9.]]), np.array([[1.], [2.]])],\
      [np.array([[5.]]), np.array([[1.]])]]
```

Each sublist has always two arrays with similar length. First two sublists should be merged because the length of their arrays is the same (`1`). I take only unique arrays. The third and fourth sublists should be merged because of the same length (`2`). These two sublists have a common array (`np.array([[8.], [9.]])`) and I only take unique arrays. Last sublist is also another split. In reality I have several sublist but I want to used the same rule for merging them. Finally, I want to get my list as:

```
arri=[[np.array([[1.]]), np.array([[2.]]),\
       np.array([[3.]]), np.array([[5.]])],\ # first chunk
      [np.array([[3.], [3.]]), np.array([[8.], [9.]]),\
       np.array([[1.], [2.]])],\ # second chunk
      [np.array([[5.]]), np.array([[1.]])]] # third chunk
```

I tried the following code but it was not successful:

```
arri=[]
for i in range (len (nums)-1):
    if (len(nums[i][0]) == len(nums[i+1][0]) and
        any((nums[i+1][0] == x).all() for x in nums[i])):
        arri.append ([nums[i], nums[i+1]])
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Dear @Mateen Ulhaq, Thanks for your attention. I have written it in my question. I want to merge sublists which the length of their arrays is the same. I start from the first sublist and check the length its array. then I go to the next sublist, if the lengths of both are the same, I merge uniques arrays. Then I go for the third, if the length is the same as previous, i merged it to them. If not, I go forwards and check the length of next one and so on,

Comment: How was your attempt not successful? Did you get an error?

Comment: Dear @Steve, I have written the expected output as `arri` in my question. It has three sublists. First sublist is created by merging unique arrays of first two sublists of input. Second sublist of `arri` is created by merging unique arrays of third and fourth sublists of input. Last one is also simply the last sublist of input. The problem with my try is that it cannot export the last sublist and still I cannot get unique arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to `groupby` and then `flatten`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def flatten(xss):
    return [x for xs in xss for x in xs]

key = lambda x: (x[0].size, x[1].size)

results = [flatten(g) for _, g in groupby(nums, key)]
```

To further keep only the unique arrays in each row, one can make use of `dict`:

```
unique_results = [
    list({tuple(x.reshape(-1)): x for x in xs}.values()) for xs in results
]
```

Which gives:

```
[
 [  array([[1.]]), array([[2.]]), array([[3.]]), array([[5.]])     ],
 [  array([[3.], [3.]]), array([[8.], [9.]]), array([[1.], [2.]])  ],
 [  array([[5.]]), array([[1.]])                                   ],
]
```

Comment: Dear @Mateen Ulhaq, this is exactly what I want. The only remained issue is that I want to have only unique arrays in each sublist. Can this be added to your solution? Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: One can filter `results` afterwards. The way to do this depends on how big the arrays are... if performance isn't an issue, you can use `dict`'s unique key property: `unique_results = [list({tuple(x.reshape(-1)): x for x in xs}.values()) for xs in results]`

Comment: to do so, I face the error: `unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Sorry, where should I put this `reshape(-1)`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for being that much supportive. I do appreciate it.